# Custom console using git bash

Tags: windows, shell, console, sh, git-bash

I understand that console applications using git bash invoke `sh.exe` but I wonder how they continue to use `sh`.

I see on console apps often you do a `sh.exe --login`.   I would guess this creates a session somewhere and I would presume that the console application would execute commands against it somehow?

Essentially I switched from UNIX to Windows.  I have tried a lot of console apps (best being `console2` and just `git-bash`) but they still do not work for me well.

Ia m annoyed enough that I fancy trying to programming a simple shell in Java. (I am a Java developer by trade.)

Any help would be great thanks to understand this, looking but searchs with `console` or `git-bash` in google generate so much random noise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the various Unix shells ported to Windows, you should be aware that most of these shells use some heuristic to make Windows look like Unix, either to build a compatibility layout or for user convenience.

For instance, the `git` command is probably stored in a `git.exe` file but your shell scripts imported from your Unix workstation all say `git` so the shell will lookup `git.exe` if it does not find `git`.

Nobe of these heuristics works perfectly, so you have to expect regular inconsistencies and disagreements, especially if your are mixing several Unix ports together.

As for the meaning of `--login`, it is synonymous to `-l` and its main effect is to decide which initialization files are read by `bash` on startup`

```
   -l        Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (see
             INVOCATION below).
```